# Ansible and docker-compose pull / up -d

Tags: docker-compose, ansible

I'm trying to run theses commands :

```sh
docker-compose pull
docker-compose up -d
docker-compose -f other_file.yaml pull
docker-compose -f other_file.yaml up -d
```

Here's my Ansible code for this specific task :

```yaml
 - name: Run docker-compose
    docker_compose:
      project_src: {{ my_project_path }}
      files:
      - docker-compose.yaml
      - other_file.yaml
```

I'm getting the error bellow

```sh
Failed to import the required Python library (Docker SDK for Python: docker (Python >= 2.7) or docker-py (Python 2.6)) on managed's Python /usr/bin/python3.
Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location.

If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter, for example via `pip install docker` or `pip install docker-py` (Python 2.6).

The error was: No module named 'docker'
```

The fact is that the python interpreter is set up in the ansible.cfg as /usr/bin/python3 which is the good one.
The version of python3 installed is 3.6.9 and the python module "docker" is installed.

Any idea on where this error comes from ? Been reading documentation, and others post all day.

Thanks !

Comment: Have you tried a `sudo pip install docker-compose` ? It is possible you simply don't have docker-compose installed.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly is unclear in the following sentence: `Failed to import the required Python library (Docker SDK for Python: docker (Python >= 2.7) or docker-py (Python 2.6)) on managed's Python /usr/bin/python3.` ? => install the relevant module on the target server => `pip3 install docker`. Even better: add a pip task to your playbook to make sur it is installed prior to running your `docker-compose` task.

Comment: What's unclear is that all the requirements are installed.
Docker-compose is installed, docker aswell. tried with the python package and the apt package.

Comment: You should pay attention to 2 potential problems: 1) on the **target** machine (i.e. not on the controller) 2) `on managed's Python /usr/bin/python3` so it should be installed in the correct python installation your are using on the target.

Comment: ^-- And since you raised that *the python interpreter is set up in the ansible.cfg as /usr/bin/python3* I would suspect the later. Possibly you'll have to see what `pip3 install docker` gives you on the node(s).

Comment: On the target machine, everything is well installed (pip3 install docker, docker-compose, ...) Python3 is located at /usr/bin/python3 on the target machine but anyway it doesn't looks like the problem since other modules are working.

(Of course if I use the command module to make a docker-compose it is working but that's not a good way of proceding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally understood why the problem occured.

I was installing the python library with `pip3 install <lib>` the fact is that it will not work if you're using sudo to run some modules in Ansible because `sudo pip3` is different from `pip3` on its own.

So quick solution ? `sudo pip3 install docker docker-compose`